# Wordpress: Permalinks for pages broken

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm using Wordpress 3.1.1 and recently reorganized my page (deleted and moved a lot of pages). Now I get 404-errors when accessing some pages (all posts and tags work fine).

I can disable the permalinks and then access all pages without problems. I can also rename the pages (e.g. contact --> contact1) and all links work again for the new names. However, if I rename them back, I get the same 404 error again. It seems like some kind of caching-problem. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

My .htaccess for the root directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache, although I doubt it will solve the issue - this sounds like a .htaccess problem. If you could provide the link here, we might be able to offer more help.

Comment: I emptied my browser cache but no change. I also thought it might be a .htaccess-problem. But my .htaccess-file seems ok (I've added it to my question). I'm also pretty sure it is a server configuration problem, because I don't get the wordpress 404-error page on this pages but my server's error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your 'trash' can in Wordpress, annoyingly items in the trash area still use a permalink, and when accessing those links you'd get 404 message.

Also delete your htaccess file (if it has no additional settings in it), and the reset your permalink settings.

Ian.

Comment: HI Ian, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it didn't help. My trash has already been empty and deleting the .htaccess-file didn't help either. After resetting the permalink strcuture, the same 404 errors occured. Is there another place where wordpress or the web server save this information and I need to reset it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. I realized, that there were some page names, that produced a server 404 and some, that don't. Then I took a closer look at my directory structure:

I access my blog from the root path (not the worpdrpess-directory which is located in it). So I can enter

> www.myurl.com

instead of

> www.myurl.com/wordpress

So far, so good. However, **I had some files in my root directory, that had the same name as the page I was trying to access.**

Eg. if there is a contact.abc (the extension doesn't matter) in the root folder, then getting

> www.myurl.com/contact

will produce a 404-error. If I rename the file everything works fine. Hopefully, that will help others as well.